# Symfony 2 - The annotation in property does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm doing symfony 2 tutorial - Doctrine and databases.

I created the file Pages.php in Entity/Pages.php

```
<?php
namespace Dproc\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @IgnoreAnnotation("fn")
 *
 */
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="pages")
 */
class Pages
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ID
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $ID;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $page_title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $page_content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $page_category;
}
```

Now i'm trying to generate setters and getters for this class using this command.

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Dproc/MainBundle/Entity/Pages
```

It tells :

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                            
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ID" in property Dp  
  roc\MainBundle\Entity\Pages::$ID does not exist, or could not be auto-loade  
  d.
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your $ID with the following code:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
```

Comment: It worked indeed. But in my table, there is ID, not Id, why should it show errors?

Comment: The name of variable is secondary, you can put any name. However, Doctrine's annotations, are case sensitive and it recognizes the identifier as `Id`

Comment: It seems like the case sensitivity comes from loading the file based on the annotation name, a wrongly cased annotation seems to work fine on a case insensitive file system

Answer (score 3):

I think this is Case Sensitive, try:

```
@ORM/Id
```